# How does NGINX resolve the Docker DNS hostnames?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, load-balancing

I want to understand the process better, but I am having trouble finding an explanation here.
I have an `app` application that prints the container ID as a http response on `/`, similar to the jwilder/whoami image.
I load balance this app with nginx using `--scale app=2` on compose. It correctly cycles between the 2 (or N) applications using the default Round-Robin method of Nginx .
How exactly does Docker and Nginx resolve and load-balance http://app/ URL in the nginx-conf?

**Edit**: More specifically, how does nginx know there are 2 ip addresses behind the `http://app/` hostname.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.9"

services: 
  app:
    build:
      context: ./Dockerfile
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-Application
    expose: 
      - "80"
    networks: 
      - application-net

  loadbalancer:
    image: nginx:latest
    depends_on: 
      - app
    ports: 
      - "80:80"
    volumes: 
      - ./cfg/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
    networks: 
      - application-net

networks: 
  application-net:
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config: 
        - subnet: "10.150.1.0/24"
```

**nginx.conf**

```
user  nginx;

events {
    worker_connections   1000;
}
http {
        server {
              listen 80;
              location / {
                proxy_pass http://app:80/;
              }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How exactly does Docker and Nginx resolve and load-balance http://app/ URL in the nginx-conf?

Docker runs a DNS service that your applications use to resolve container names. That is why, for a container started on a network other than the default `bridge` network, you will see that `resolv.conf` does not point to your regular DNS server:

```
$ docker run --rm --net=net0 alpine cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep nameserver
nameserver 127.0.0.11
```

Comment: That is fine, but my question is rather, how does Nginx know, that there are 2 (or N number of) containers running behind the `app` hostname

Comment: It doesn't! This answer is the entire story. Remember that a DNS response can contain multiple addresses; if there are multiple `app` containers, nginx just asks for the hostname `app` and receives a response that contains multiple results.

Comment: Aaah right. That one i totally forgot. Thanks! Marking your answer as accepted.